# Let $f(x)=x^3+x$. If $h$ is the inverse function of $f$, then $h'(2)$ is equal to what?

Tags: calculus

I know that you're supposed to use the formula
$$h'(x) = \frac1{f'(h(x))}.$$
But I don't know what to do afterwards?

Comment: Put dollar signs around your math and it will display better

Comment: If you substitute $x=2$, what do you get? Can you evaluate the resulting expression?

Comment: Substitute $x=2$ into what equation?

Comment: Also note that the "formula" you mentioned is a rearrangement of the chain rule, since $f(h(x))=x$ as the definition of inverse, and noting that $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x)$ = 1 gives the result after differentiating both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(1) = 2$ so $h(2) = 1$.  Put $y = h(x)$ and use implicit diff;
$$y^3 + y = x$$
so 
$$(3y^2 + 1)y' = 1$$
Now put $x = 2$ and you have
$$(3 + 1)y'(2) = 1$$
so $y'(2)= 1/4.$

Answer (score 0):

If $h'(x) = \frac1{f'(h(x))}$ then $h'(x) = \frac 1 {3h^2(x) + 1}$

If $f(x) = x^3 + x = 2 => x = 1 => h(2) = 1$ so $h'(2) =  \frac 1 {3h^2(x) + 1} =  \frac 1 {3*1 + 1}= \frac 1 4$